# PSQLException "Could not open SSL root certificate file" when attempting SSL connection with Postgres via JDBC

Tags: postgresql, ssl, jdbc, datasource

In Java 15, using the PostgreSQL JDBC Driver (ver. 42.2.18, JDBC4.2) from jdbc.postgresql.org with this [`DataSource`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/javax/sql/DataSource.html):

```java
PGSimpleDataSource ds = new PGSimpleDataSource();
ds.setServerNames( new String[] { "my-server-address" } );
ds.setPortNumbers( new int[] { 25060 } );
ds.setSsl( true );
ds.setDatabaseName( "mydb" );
ds.setUser( "scott" );
ds.setPassword( "tiger" );
this.dataSource = ds;
```

…the code `Connection conn = this.dataSource.getConnection();` throws this exception:

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Could not open SSL root certificate file /Users/basilbourque/.postgresql/root.crt.

I know my Postgres 12 server is set up for SSL connections, as my [IntelliJ Ultimate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JetBrains#IntelliJ_IDEA) has a database access feature ([DataGrip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JetBrains#DataGrip)) that is successfully connecting with SSL (TLS) protection.

So what is wrong my `DataSource` configuration in JDBC?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thanks to [this Github issue](https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/issues/1307) page for the pgjdbc driver, I found this post by davecramer:

> As of 42.2.5 ssl=true implies verify-full as per the release notes. If you wish to get the old behaviour use sslmode=require

Sure enough, replacing `ds.setSsl( true );` with `ds.setSslMode( "require" );` allowed my JDBC driver make a connection via `DataSource`.

```java
        PGSimpleDataSource ds = new PGSimpleDataSource();
        ds.setServerNames( new String[] { "my-server-address" } );
        ds.setPortNumbers( new int[] { 25060 } );
        ds.setSslMode( "require" );  // Replaces: ds.setSsl( true );
        ds.setDatabaseName( "mydb" );
        ds.setUser( "scott" );
        ds.setPassword( "tiger" );
        this.dataSource = ds;
```

I have no idea what any of these SSL/TLS related options are actually doing, but this worked for me to connect to my DigitalOcean managed Postgres database server.

The following code snippet now runs successfully:

```java
        try
                (
                        Connection conn = this.dataSource.getConnection() ;
                        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement() ;
                )
        {
            String sql =
                    """
                    SELECT uuid_generate_v1()
                    ;
                    """;
            try (
                    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery( sql ) ;
            )
            {
                while ( rs.next() )
                {
                    UUID uuid = rs.getObject( 1 , UUID.class );
                    System.out.println( "uuid = " + uuid );
                }
            }
        }
        catch ( SQLException e )
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: With  these options, PostgreSQL uses encrypted communication, but no attempt is made to verify the authenticity of the server. So you could fall prey to man-in-the-middle attacks. If that is no concern, your settings are good.

Answer (score 0):

For people Googling the error message, also consider whether you meant to connect with SSL at all. I had checked the wrong box in DBeaver when I meant to use "SSH tunnel".